# How to hardcore values in Select statement in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I was wondering if there is a way we could put a few string values on the select statement to create variables to be used later.

E.g.

```
SELECT 'A','B" AS AB FROM TEMP_TABLE
```

RESULT

```
AB
A
B
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sysibm.sysdummy1`:

```
select 'A' as AB from sysibm.sysdumm1 union all
select 'B' as AB from sysibm.sysdumm1
```

Answer (score 0):

Db2 has [global variables](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0050499.html) which you could consider.

Otherwise, you can use a `VALUES` statement.  E.g.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(VALUES ('A', 1,2),('B', 1,3)) AS VARS(AB,I,J)
```

which returns

```
AB|I|J
--|-|-
A |1|2
B |1|3
```